# Get Bounding Box used By queryRenderedFeatures

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have an application that serves vector tiles. The features in the tiles are clickable. When a user clicks the map, I pass mapbox-gl's `queryRenderedFeatures` a 5 x 5px bounding box around the clicked point.

Is there a way to ascertain the lat-lon bounding box that mapbox uses to query its cached tiles? I would like to have this bounding box so I can query the database for the features around the clicked point. I can use the ids of the features in the vector tiles, but this becomes cumbersome/untenable when there are 1000s of features.

Here's how I am getting features near point, where:

- `map` is the mapbox map object
- `mapboxLayers` are the names of the layers I want to query
- `point` is `point` property of the click event

```
export const getMapFeaturesNearPoint = ({ map, mapboxLayers, point }) => {
  const { x, y } = point;

  const halfPixels = 5;
  // set bbox as 5px rectangle around clicked point
  const bbox = [
    [x - halfPixels, y - halfPixels],
    [x + halfPixels, y + halfPixels],
  ];
  const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(bbox, { layers: [...mapboxLayers] })
  return features;
};
```

**Note:** I have tried doing the following with the bbox defined above: `bbox.map(pt => map.unproject(pt))` to get the lat lon bounding box. From my examination of the mapboxgl source code, it seems the process to unproject queryRenderedFeatures coordinates is a bit more complex than that.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of how you are passing `queryRenderedFeatures` "1 10 X 10px bounding box around the clicked point"? It sounds like you are trying to figure out how to convert this pixel bounding box into a bounding box defined by geographic coordinates -- is that correct?

Comment: @AdrianaBabakanian thanks for the comment! Yes, I am trying to figure out how to convert the pixel bounding box to geographic coordinate bounding box. I have expanded on my question with some source code, and a (hopefully) more coherent description of how I have tried to use `map.unproject`

Comment: @AdrianaBabakanian any ideas here?

Answer (score 2):

Not very clear to me what you are trying to get, but conceptually speaking, what any `queryRenderedFeatures` is doing with no filters, is basically find all the tiles in the cache (the ones cached are in the viewport), then per tile, get all the features on them, and merge them all into the result. So, if you use `queryRenderedFeatures` with no arguments or with only a options argument is equivalent to passing a bounding box encompassing the entire map viewport.

You can check the source code of [`query_features.js` file in Mapbox github repo](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/a85e997efe8085da765cd4430ea640a92fdbcda1/src/source/query_features.js#L41)

With those features in the viewport, it would be easy to reduce them to a lnglat bounding box through a `.reduce` function that you can use, for instance, as a bounding box to use `map.fitBounds`.

```
var coordinates = points;

var bounds = coordinates.reduce(function(bounds, coord) {
  return bounds.extend(coord);
}, new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(coordinates[0], coordinates[0]));

map.fitBounds(bounds, {
  padding: { top: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50, right: 50 },
  easing(t) {
      return t * (2 - t);
  }
});
```

But as said, not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Other option would be to use the canvas width and height and unproject them... I found this code while ago,

```
const canvas = map.getCanvas()
const w = canvas.width
const h = canvas.height
const cUL = map.unproject ([0,0]).toArray()
const cUR = map.unproject ([w,0]).toArray()
const cLR = map.unproject ([w,h]).toArray()
const cLL = map.unproject ([0,h]).toArray()
const coordinates = [cUL,cUR,cLR,cLL,cUL]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using a 5px bbox as the first argument to queryRenderedFeatures, see the code snippet. Unprojecting those "coordinates" gives me a different lat/lon bounding box than the one that queryRenderedFeatures returns

Comment: So what you want is real coordinates of the 5px bbox, right?? Curious on why unproject the 5px bbox returns wrong lat/lng, have you seen better results on different zoom levels?

Comment: Querying the db with the lat/lon given by unproject gives a different count of features than queryRenderedFeatures (no matter the postgis function used). It could be an issue w/ my query, but my examination of queryRenderedFeatures indicated that there is more going on there than a simple unproject.

Comment: It that's the case and you can repro it providing a Minimal Reproducible Example, this may be a bug worth reporting to Mapbox